# Using css property "transition: all", I add a dynamic class: (<div className={`${show ? "show" : "hide"}></div> ), but my animation doesn't work

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a `Modal` component. I would like that when the modal appears, it appears with a transition just like when it disappears. This is currently very jerky, why and how can I fix it?

I would like that when the modal is shown it is shown with an animation and the same behavior when the modal disappears (click on the `button`).

thank you very much for the help, I know I will learn a lot.

```
//content of styles.css
.modal {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.show {
  transform: translateY(0%);
}

.hide {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

app.js

import Modal from "./modal";
/*
const Modal = ({ show, children }) => {
 return <div className={`modal ${show ? "show" : "hide"}`}>. 
 {children} </div>;
};
export default Modal;
*/
import ModalContent from "./modalContent";
/*
  const ModalContent = ({ show }) => {
   const showModal = () => {
    show();
   };
  return <button onClick={showModal}> close modal</button>;
};
export default ModalContent;
*/
export default function App() {
 const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
 const closeModal = () => {
  setShow(false);
};

useEffect(() => setShow(true), []);

return (
  <div className="App">
    {show && (
      <Modal show={show}>
        <ModalContent show={closeModal} />
      </Modal>
    )}
  </div>
 );
}
```

**I updated my code:**

[this is my live code](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-resonance-joiyt)

Comment: Changing props of a React component leads to rerendering it, i.e. removing the old DOM subtree and adding the new one with new attributes etc. That is why the old `<div class="modal show">` and the new `<div class="modal hide">` are different DOM elements, so it's not the change of the CSS property of the same element that CSS transitions can handle

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn what can I do? thanks crack!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in your demo modal disappears immediately, without any transition. It seems, that it's cause by re-rendering of whole App component, on `show` state change. Extracting `Modal` component out of App do the trick for me:

```
const Modal = ({ show, children }) => {
  useEffect(() => {}, [show]);
  return <div className={`modal ${show ? "show" : "hide"}`}>{children} </div>;
};

export default function App() {
```

Second point - you can't control initial setup just with with css transition. Transition appears when something (class, attribute, pseudoclass)  changes on the given element. To get around this and have smooth modal appearance, you can setup one-time `useEffect` in the App component, which will change `show` state from `false` to `true`. My overall snippet:

```
const Modal = ({ show, children }) => {
    return <div className={`modal ${show ? "show" : "hide"}`}>{children}        </div>;
};

export default function App() {

const ModalContent = ({ show }) => {
  const showModal = () => {
    show();
  };
  return <button onClick={showModal}> close modal</button>;
};

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const closeModal = () => {
  setShow(false);
};

useEffect(() => setShow(true), [])

return (
  <div className="App">
    <Modal show={show}>
      <ModalContent show={closeModal} />
    </Modal>
  </div>
);
}
```

Comment: you are great, I learned something. Look I listened to you but I have doubt in this scenario: `{show && (Modal....`  My modal is shown without transition, how could I fix it to have an animation. I updated my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-wing-6m5uu

Comment: You code works just fine. Please remove this snippet from `modal.js`
`setShow((fdas) => {
    console.log(fdas);
  });`
And modal will appear with transition, as well as disappear.

Comment: When updating the DOM or changing the view part you should use useLayoutEffect for smooth transitions this will wait for the DOM to load then it fires the events.